# how to avoid running burst operations in laravel middleware when refresh

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

im using laravel middleware `(visits)` to create visits record in database like this:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{

    Visit::create([
        'ip' => 'user ip',
        'browser' => 'user browser',
        'url' => url()->current(),
        'referer' => $request->headers->get('referer'),
    ]);


    return $next($request);
}
```

the problem is here:
If the user refreshes the page quickly, a large number of records will be saved

what can i do to prevent this?

Comment: *"a large number of records will be saved"* - 1) throttle the request; 2) put a flag on session that user has already visited that url recently. that being said, your code might bogged down if you have a fairly large visitor. people sold analytics solution to alleviate developer's headache.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [unique job](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#unique-jobs) with some of the parameters that saves the Visit instead of directly saving it, that should work.

Comment: yes, its working. but with database queue i think it would be a heavy operation. what is your opinion about doing this by sessions??

Comment: By session is a different approach, but not sure if its really reliable, because if you have multiple consecutive request by holding ctrl-r then the session doesn’t know you have visited the page